# Fetching a column value using KEY_ROWID in SQLite

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch a value from a column using KEY_ROWID at SQLite table in Android. But I am getting wrong value. For example, when I tried to fetch the value from sixth row, I got the value from second row. Then for fifth row, I got the first row value. For fourth row, I got null. I have altogether six rows in total in my database. What could be wrong?
My database is

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID   = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_IDNUM   = "_idnum";
 public static final String KEY_SIMCARD = "_simcard";
 public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "_description";
 public static final String KEY_MODEL = "_model";
 public static final String KEY_TIMEINSTANCE = "timeinstance";
 public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
 public static final String KEY_LOCATIONAUTOUPDATE = "locationupdate";
 public static final String KEY_OVERSPEED = "overspeed";
 public static final String KEY_MOVEMENT = "movement";
 public static final String KEY_GEOFENCE = "geofence";
 public static final String KEY_TIMEZONE = "timezone";
 public static final String KEY_AUTHORIZE = "authorize";
 public static final String KEY_IMAGE  = "image";
 public static final String KEY_ACTIVATE  = "activate";
 public static final String KEY_NUMOFUSE  = "number_of_use";
 private static final String TAG = "TrackerDBAdapter";
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBTrackerList";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "TBTrackerList";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 5;
 private final Context mCtx;
 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
          "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
          KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
          KEY_IDNUM + "," +
          KEY_SIMCARD + "," +
          KEY_DESCRIPTION + "," +
          KEY_MODEL + "," +
          KEY_TIMEINSTANCE + "," +
          KEY_PASSWORD + "," +
          KEY_LOCATIONAUTOUPDATE + "," +
          KEY_OVERSPEED + "," +
          KEY_MOVEMENT + "," +
          KEY_GEOFENCE + "," +
          KEY_TIMEZONE + "," +
          KEY_AUTHORIZE + "," + 
          KEY_IMAGE + "," + 
          KEY_ACTIVATE + "," +
          KEY_NUMOFUSE + "," + 
          " UNIQUE (" + KEY_ROWID +"));";

 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
```

I am trying to fetch idnum(KEY_IDNUM) using rowid(KEY_ROWID) as follow.

```
public String fetchIDnumByRowid(long rowid) throws SQLException{             
     Cursor mCursor = null;
     String retstring = null;
     mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE, KEY_PASSWORD,
               KEY_LOCATIONAUTOUPDATE, KEY_OVERSPEED, KEY_MOVEMENT, KEY_GEOFENCE, KEY_TIMEZONE, KEY_AUTHORIZE, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_ACTIVATE, KEY_NUMOFUSE}, 
               KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowid, null, null, null, null, null);  

     if(mCursor != null){
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        retstring = mCursor.getString(1);
     }

     return retstring;
 }
```

EDIT1:
When I fetch all rows and check row by row to these idnum, all are correct.
Just that when I fetch as shown above, I have problem.

Comment: try     `mCursor=  mdb.query(SQLITE_TABLE,new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
               KEY_IDNUM, KEY_SIMCARD, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_MODEL, KEY_TIMEINSTANCE, KEY_PASSWORD,
               KEY_LOCATIONAUTOUPDATE, KEY_OVERSPEED, KEY_MOVEMENT, KEY_GEOFENCE, KEY_TIMEZONE, KEY_AUTHORIZE, KEY_IMAGE, KEY_ACTIVATE, KEY_NUMOFUSE}, 
              KEY_ROWID + "=?",
              new String[] {String.valueOf(rowid)},null,null,null,null);` and also move  `retstring = mCursor.getString(1)` outside the if block

Comment: @Raghunandan, I still have the same problem.

Comment: not sure what the problem is but the above worked for me

Comment: Now I found my problem. I made the table, then I deleted rows and created rows again. For the newly created rows, they don't start from 1. That is the problem.

Comment: @Raghunandan: I delete a row as return mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE,KEY_IDNUM + "='"+ idnum+ "'", null) > 0; But the KEY_ROWID is not updated upon delete. How can I update the KEY_ROWID for the leftover rows.